# Android call onClick method without Clicking

Tags: android, onclick

I want to use existing onClick method to make my program simpler.
It consists of onClick method and other method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()){
  case R.id.button1:
    ....
    break;
  }
}

void foo(){
  ....
  onClick(????);
}
```

Is there any way to make it do the same behaviour like when i click it on the phone?

Comment: [performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()) :)

Comment: but how to determine which button do the click programmatically?

Comment: why would you do onclick without clicking?

Comment: Use myButton.performClick();

Comment: @VictorioPui it will call view onClickListener ,this will work as you explained in question

Comment: i get it now, thanks Iftikar Urrhman Khan it works now :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use `View.performClick()`

[reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick())

Answer (score 3):

`performClick()` will play a sound just like if the user clicked on that view, therefore in most cases it's better to use `callOnClick()`, which will call the `OnClickListener` without playing any click sound. (Available since API level 15)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) myView.callOnClick(); //won't play sound
else myView.performClick(); //will play sound
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler(  );
    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // call the method below
        }
    },0 );
```

Comment: Works perfectly with 'performClick();'

Answer (score -1):

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{         

Button mBtnAutomaticClick;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_bug);
             mBtnAutomaticClick = findViewById(R.id.automatic_click_demo);
             mBtnAutomaticClick.setOnClickListener(this);
             mBtnAutomaticClick.performClick(); // for automatic click event
          }
      }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.automatic_click_demo:
           // your code
           break;
    }
}
```

When activity will call your code which you have written inside onClick will be called automatically.