# How do I always display the Infowindow in Mapbox android without having to click on the marker?

Tags: java, android, maps, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am working on mapbox android. I need the infowindow to be shown on top of all markers when the activity is loaded, without having to click on the markers to see each info window.How do I acheive this functionality in mapbox?

Here is the code:-

```
  mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap map) {

                mapboxMap = map;
  mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title("hello")
                        .snippet("I am here")
                .position(new LatLng(33.948,-118.08)));

                mapboxMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapboxMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {
                   //What do I give here so that marker click is not at all needed to inflate the Infowindow.
                           return null;
                    }
                });
)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to open infowindow bydefault

```
Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(latLng)
                 .title("Title")
                 .snippet("Snippet")
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                 .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
 marker.showInfoWindow();
```

but this working only for one marker,fOR multiple marker it opens infowindow for last marker.
[Source From this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899619/opening-infowindow-automatically-when-adding-marker-google-maps-v2-android)

Comment: showInfoWindow is asking for two parameters- mapboxMap and mapView. Even after giving those two parameters, the info window is not appearing. It appears only on clicking.

Comment: put this code in your getmapAsync method. have you done same?

Comment: This shows defualt infoWindow. If I have to inflate a custom infoWindow, how can I do in the same way?

Comment: for custom infowindow use this link "http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/"

Answer (score 0):

You can Call View.Performclick() when add marker to Map.
Check out this post.
[Android call onClick method without Clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732398/android-call-onclick-method-without-clicking)

Comment: To which object do I call View.PerformClick method? I cannot call on marker object.

Comment: you can call onmapReady().

Comment: I have written the above code itself inside the onMapReady() method. How do I again call the same method to set performclick() action? Note:- Please see the edit now.

Comment: call mapboxMap.performClick();