# Android : Trigger textView's onClick() forcecfully

Tags: android

Say I have defined an `onClickListener` for a `TextView` and I want to trigger it once without having to click on it - Is this possible?

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250395/3676200

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android call onClick method without Clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732398/android-call-onclick-method-without-clicking)

Answer (score 2):

you just have to call performClick() on it

```
textView.performClick()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button);
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Add your code here 
   } 
});
```

to perform automatic click use below

```
textView.performClick();
```